# How to use the pickle file in android studio without deploying pickle file over the internet

Tags: android, android-studio, pickle

Basically i am doing an Android app, for that i have to use the pickle file. i know a method in which we deploy the pickle file on internet and use the url in android studio. So can i store the pickle file inside of android studio and then use it. Is it possible ??

I want to store the pickle inside the android studio

Comment: Do you want to include your apk with the pickle file in advance?
Or do you want to download once and use it later without re-downloading?

Comment: I just want to add it like how we add the image file in drawable folder. So i want to include apk with pickle file in advance.